# mysqlconnect to scalable gear on OpenShift

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

I'm trying to connect to my mysql DB on OpenShift Online that has been set up as a scalable gear, and the connection URL that OpenShift provides

```
mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/
```

does not connect. When using this as the localhost parameter within mysql_connect(), I am unable to connect to my DB. When I set the gear up as non-scalable, which provides the actual host ip and port when adding mysql to the gear, this works perfectly. Below is an example of how I would input this.

```
$DBconnect = mysql_connect("mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/", "UserName","PassWord","DB");
```

Does anyone have any experience connecting to a scalable gear on OpenShift, and what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some simple error processing code to help you work out what might be going wrong, like

```
$DBconnect = mysql_connect("mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/", "UserName","PassWord","DB");

if (!$DBconnect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

This may well give you an error message that allows you to work out what the problem is!

HINT:

It looks to me like this is expecting that you have created variables called

```
$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST = 'SomeHostName';
$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT = 'SomePortNumber';
```

before running the mysql_connect, have you done that? Or included their file with these already defined?

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly for helping out, I will try the error handling as recommended. I did grep the hostname and port # and substitute this in. Although still was not able to connect. Thought it was my sql commands, but everything works fine on non-scalable. Thanks again, will provide update once I get the errors returned.